# CiviCRM permission edit message templates only applies to email templates not print/merge templates

Tags: permissions, message-templates

Can anyone confirm that the edit message template(s) (or edit user-driven message templates) permission only applies to email templates and not also to print/merge templates? Or am I missing a different permission or configuration to control them both?

I have found that even though I have limited the ability for people to update or add new email templates they can get around this by choosing the print/merge document option. Since the list of templates is the same for both this is problematic.

I've included sample images of both activities for reference - in the print/merge document activity you can see the save as new template check mark is available while it is not for the email activity. (Same user for both activities, the user has no permissions turned on for ANY of the edit message template options.)

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.39.4

[image]
[image]